# how can I confirm with certainty that my files are being served from cache?

Tags: javascript, apache, performance, caching, google-chrome-devtools

I have set this code (below) into the virtual host configuration in my Apache server (CentOS) with the intention of ensuring the user only downloads these large static assets one time.

Notably, I have a large (bundled, minified) javascript, css, etc.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpe?g|png|gif|js|css|swf|mp3|mp4|webm)$">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</FilesMatch>
```

The issue is, I can't tell if they are being served from cache or not. Even with the disable cache checkbox not ticked, if I inspect their response headers with Chrome Dev Tools (in the network tab), I do indeed see an expires header set one year in the future, however, I also see the size being reported as 355kb and the time loaded at over 1 second!

Does anyone with more Apache/Dev Tools experience than me know what is going on here? Do I trust the time reported, or the expires header? How can I know for sure that my assets are correctly being served from cache?

Thanks for your help

Comment: The user can override expiry timers and always download directly if they so want.

Comment: What's your point though? Sure it's possible, but the vast majority of users will not do that.

Comment: Point is there is no 100%.

Comment: Ah, got you. Well I'm not saying I want to confirm that they are served from cache 100% of the time, but that (under normal circumstances) I can be 100% confident they are being served as expected (from the cache). Just updated title to avoid confusion. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to caching, which often get confused:

1. Items are added to the cache so they can be used **without** going back to server if used within the cache time. This saves network requests at all and is the prime benefit of caching (see [why Page Weight Doesn't Matter but latency does](http://www.nateberkopec.com/2015/11/05/page-weight-doesnt-matter.html)).
2. Items can be served from the cache **after** the cache time, if it turns out the cached version is still valid after a quick double check with the server (which will return a 304 response to say "your cached version is still valid - cache it for another bit"). This is good for larger assets (images, videos) but for smaller assets (html and css) it's likely the network request to double check the assets is still valid will take almost as long as the request to download the file again. So there are smaller gains with this caching.

To test these two scenarios in Chrome open developer tools, you **must** make sure that "Disable cache" is not ticked in the Network tab. It is by default as, when developer tools are open, it's likely you are developing and want to see the latest version.

Then you need to be aware that there are three ways to request a page which affects caching:

1. You browse to a page. If the have not got it in the cache you will see a status of 200 and a size. If you have visited before you, and have a valid version in the cache, then you will still see a 200 but "(from cache)" will appear in the Size column. And finally if in the cache but expired, then you might see a 304 if, after checking with the server, the cached version is in fact still the latest version.
2. You press F5 or reload the page. This is an explicit request by the user to double check the content. So **even** if it's still within the cache time the browser will double check and at best you will get a 304 response. It's easy to misunderstand this one when testing.
3. Ctrl+F5. This basically says "delete the cache and start again". Items will be downloaded again even if in the cache and valid so you should **only** get 200 responses, no "(from cache)" and no 304s.

I've had a double check of your site and can see the css and jpegs are correctly added to the cache and served from the cache. Additionally hitting F5 shows 304s as expected. So all looks good.

A few other things to be aware of:

- How the browser & server decides on whether the cached version is still valid, is by one of two methods and Etags are often used for this. But Etags and GZip causes problems with Apache due to a [long standing bug in Apache](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45023). See my post here: https://www.tunetheweb.com/performance/http-performance-headers/etag/.  I'd turn off ETags and turn on Gzip on your server (not sure why you have gzip off but definitely worth turning on).
- Your HTML page is not being cached. This is often done for cache-busting techniques but I think it's a missed opportunity. When browsing around a site it's nice to get instant responses rather than wait for the HTML to download again, even if the assets it uses are served from the cache. I've a [blog post on caching](https://www.tunetheweb.com/performance/http-performance-headers/caching/) for further discussion on this.
- Browser can ignore caches in certain circumstances (e.g. if dev tools open with disable cache, or cache has filled up, or turned off) so you can't depend on caching, but if set up right it can help both your user and your server a lot.
- Caches are a lot smaller than you think (see [why Page Weight Doesn't Matter but latency does](http://www.nateberkopec.com/2015/11/05/page-weight-doesnt-matter.html) link again). So again assume worst case and that it's not in the cache.
- You have Keep-Alives disabled on your server and that's a massive performance hit right there. See here the [waterfall graph here](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/160117_9P_CN2/1/details/) to see the impact this is causing you. Each resource request (whether an initial request or a check cache 304 request) requires setting up of a new connection (orange), and also new SSL negotiation (purple) and these are large proportions of the request, Without those the responses would be considerably quicker. Keep-Alives are on by default in Apache so did you explicitly turn this off? And if so why? See [my blog post to see where to check the Keep-Alive settings in Apache](https://www.tunetheweb.com/performance/http-performance-headers/keep-alive/).

BTW. Apologies for linking to so many of my own blog posts in that last section and if that seems like spam, but I have a active interest in all this (hence why I blog on it), and have attempted to answer the question here on SO and just included the links for further information. So hopefully this won't offend anyone.

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot for your response! "You browse to a page. If you have visited before you, and have a valid version in the cache, then you will still see a 200 but "(from cache)" will appear in the Size column." -- THIS is my beef. Since I have my expires headers set to 1 year in the future, I expect to be seeing 200 and "(from cache)", but I'm not, I'm seeing 304 and a significant size/time in their respective fields. Doesn't that sound like something to be concerned about? Seems to me like my assets aren't being delivered from cache. The disable cache checkbox is not ticked.

Comment: It works for me. Are you pressing F5 to refresh or just browsing? F5 or refresh will always show 304s. And your significant time is due to your keep-alive settings being incorrect, as mentioned, so even a 304 takes a lot longer than it should.

Comment: Oh! After re-reading your second point (in the section I quoted) above I caught what you mean. I was indeed explicitly doing a refresh, not a hard refresh, just a normal refresh and I didn't realize that under those circumstances you will never get a (from cache). Now, when just browsing around normally, I do see (from cache) as expected. You are the man; I'm going to read the posts you mentioned. I did NOT intentionally disable Keep-Alive, how were you able to tell for sure that it is disabled? Thank you.

Comment: The header shows "Connection: Close" instead of "Connection: Keep-Alive". And also WebpageTest link shows the tell tale orange and purple bars.

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking at the headers though and I don't see any mention of "Connection: Close". This is what I am seeing for the headers: http://i.imgur.com/daMAsCk.png

Comment: The headers from cache or 304 responses are sometimes different than the real headers. Look at a real 200 response.

Comment: I see it now, perfect. Thank you. Going to attempt to move this to chat now so I can ask you something else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100899/discussion-between-brian-fitzgerald-and-bazzadp).